# Cannot find symbol in Java recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to help a friend implement a Trie structure in Java although my programming is not that great, let along my Java. I found an implementation [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2070706) and tried to run it on IDEA IntelliJ.

The error I receive is,

```
Error:(87, 41) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getWords()
  location: variable children of type com.company.TrieNode[]
```

I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting this error. I have a feeling it might have to do with the loop? I want to get the code running before I analyze it but this error is a hurdle.

I've already tried `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart` within IntelliJ but it comes up with the same error. I think this might be a Java problem.

The following is what I have (credits to the aforementioned link),

**Main.java**

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Trie myTrie = new Trie();
        myTrie.addWord("Khalid");
    }
}
```

**Trie.java**

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Khalid on 5 December.
 */
public class Trie
{
    private TrieNode root;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Trie()
    {
        root = new TrieNode();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a word to the Trie
     * @param word
     */
    public void addWord(String word)
    {
        root.addWord(word.toLowerCase());
    }

    /**
     * Get the words in the Trie with the given
     * prefix
     * @param prefix
     * @return a List containing String objects containing the words in
     *         the Trie with the given prefix.
     */
    public List getWords(String prefix)
    {
        //Find the node which represents the last letter of the prefix
        TrieNode lastNode = root;
        for (int i=0; i<prefix.length(); i++)
        {
            lastNode = lastNode.getNode(prefix.charAt(i));

            //If no node matches, then no words exist, return empty list
            if (lastNode == null) return new ArrayList();
        }

        //Return the words which eminate from the last node
        return lastNode.getWords();
    }
}
```

**TrieNode.java**

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Khalid on 5 December.
 */
public class TrieNode {
    private TrieNode parent;
    private TrieNode[] children;
    private boolean isLeaf;     //Quick way to check if any children exist
    private boolean isWord;     //Does this node represent the last character of a word
    private char character;     //The character this node represents

    /**
     * Constructor for top level root node.
     */
    public TrieNode() {
        children = new TrieNode[26];
        isLeaf = true;
        isWord = false;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for child node.
     */
    public TrieNode(char character) {
        this();
        this.character = character;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a word to this node. This method is called recursively and
     * adds child nodes for each successive letter in the word, therefore
     * recursive calls will be made with partial words.
     *
     * @param word the word to add
     */
    protected void addWord(String word) {
        isLeaf = false;
        int charPos = word.charAt(0) - 'a';

        if (children[charPos] == null) {
            children[charPos] = new TrieNode(word.charAt(0));
            children[charPos].parent = this;
        }

        if (word.length() > 1) {
            children[charPos].addWord(word.substring(1));
        } else {
            children[charPos].isWord = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the child TrieNode representing the given char,
     * or null if no node exists.
     *
     * @param c
     * @return
     */
    protected TrieNode getNode(char c) {
        return children[c - 'a'];
    }

    /**
     * Returns a List of String objects which are lower in the
     * hierarchy that this node.
     *
     * @return
     */
    protected List getWords() {
        //Create a list to return
        List list = new ArrayList();

        //If this node represents a word, add it
        if (isWord) {
            list.add(toString());
        }

        //If any children
        if (!isLeaf) {
            //Add any words belonging to any children
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                if (children[i] != null)
                    list.addAll(children.getWords());
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the String that this node represents.
     * For example, if this node represents the character t, whose parent
     * represents the charater a, whose parent represents the character
     * c, then the String would be "cat".
     *
     * @return
     */

    public String toString() {
        if (parent == null) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return parent.toString() + new String(new char[]{character});
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You're tying to call `getWords()` on `children` which is an instance of `TrieNode[]` and doesn't have such a method.

Comment: Isn't `getWords()` defined within the `TrieNode` class?

Comment: `TrieNode[]` is not the same as `TrieNode`.

Comment: It should probably be `children[i].getWords()`.

Comment: I was under the impression that `TrieNode[]` refers to an array of `TrieNode`. Does this mean I have to define a new class?

Comment: It is indeed an array of `TrieNode`. But you can't call a type's methods on an array of that type. You would have to reference the specific instance in question.

Comment: Yes, `children[i].getWords()` did it. Thanks. Can you please add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to call `getWords()` on `children`, which is an *array* of `TrieNode`. Presumably the intent is to collect the result of each child node. Since you're already in a loop, you just need to update the code to reference the current item:

```
list.addAll(children[i].getWords());
```